# Web API 2 Http Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am disgusted not have found a solution to this problem.

I started creating a new api using Web API 2 and just cannot get the POST and PUT to work. The Get all and Get single item works perfectly fine.

There are no related articles anywhere, and those that i've found relates only to Gets and Web API, but not Web API 2.

Any assistance would do please.

```
    // POST: api/checkOuts
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(checkOut))]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostcheckOut(checkOut co)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.checkOuts.Add(checkOut);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (checkOutExists(checkOut.id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = checkOut.id }, checkOut);
    }
```

So basically, I'm just attempting to get a debug into the method.

Was especially disappointed in this link as it covered almost everything, but ai. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing

Regards

Comment: Also can you post the surrounding class declaration and are you setting your request type to HTTP POST in your REST client when testing it?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post with the code as requested. Yes I am setting it to post and tested with Chrome Postman, FireFox RestClient, and FireFox Poster, error code 405 has been returned. PS! Routing is not an issue.

Comment: There's this article about troubleshooting 405 errors after publishing WebAPI 2 applications, I'm not sure if that provides any help: [http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications)

Comment: I've tested this now and still no luck, at least I have a better understanding of the 405 error now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a working code

```
        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(CheckOut))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] CheckOut checkOut)
        {
            if (checkOut == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid passed data");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.checkOuts.Add(checkOut);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (checkOutExists(checkOut.id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = checkOut.Id }, checkOut);
        }
```

I've declared CheckOut class to be like this :

```
public class CheckOut
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

The Key things here are :

1- You need to add [FromBody] to your Api method.
2- I've tested it using Fiddler, 
    i- by choosing POST action.
    ii- content-type: application/json.
    iii- passing {"Id":1,"Property2":"Anything"} in the message body.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same 405 error. I'm not sure if it's something to do with the environment or what, as I created a new API project and still had the same issues

Comment: Would you like me to send you the project that I have tested this with? I can share it with you.

Comment: Thanks, would be appreciated.

Comment: You can download the project file from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/2727kx7f61dr8cn/WebApi2Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Solution worked fine. Weirdly enough my code is identical and is still not working. Sure it must be something to do with the references or in the web.config, but can continue the investigation using your solution.