# POST /api/Messaging/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have some angular attempting to post to a web API. 
I have got this working before but keep getting issues with CORS.

I have put this in global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

this is the API Controller action signature:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]Message message)
```

both [FromUri] and [FromBody] do not work

I have tried:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

in the WebApiConfig.cs while removing Application_BeginRequest code in asax file and I get the same message which is: 
405 (Method Not Allowed)

And the Controller:

```
 public class MessagingController : ApiController
    {
        private IMessagingRepository DataRepository;

        public MessagingController()
        {
            DataRepository = new DataRepositoryFactory().GetMessagingInstance();
        }

        public List<Message> Get([FromUri]MessageGetModel model)
        {
            var result = DataRepository.GetMessages(model.FromId, model.ToId);

            return result;
        }

        public Message Get(string messageId)
        {
            var result = DataRepository.GetMessage(messageId);

            return result;
        }

        public void Post([FromUri]Message message)
        {
            message.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
            DataRepository.GetDataRepository().Save(message);

            DataRepository.PostOrUpdateThread(message);

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: As requested - the controller

Comment: FromUri seems odd on a POST, I believe that should be [FromBody]

Comment: It doesnt matter, the action should still be called, the model would just come through as null

Comment: Are you sure that the model and what you send is correct?

Answer (score 0):

1- Change [FromUri] to [FromBody] because you normally post the data through the message body not through the query string, normally the query string is for Get requests.

2- Remove your code from Application_BeginRequest because EnableCors is enough, and it will add the Allow headers, and by adding them again through the code of Application_BeginRequest, you get problems of duplication for the same header in your response.

3- You can add the Route Attribute or RoutePrefix to your method/controller so for your Post method, replace it to be something like this:

```
[Route("api/Messaging")]
public void Post([FromBody]Message message)
{
    message.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    DataRepository.GetDataRepository().Save(message);

    DataRepository.PostOrUpdateThread(message);
}
```

4- Test with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and make sure that you add your message into the request body either in a JSON format or url encoded.

5- Make sure that use set the "content-type" header to "application/json" if you set the message in the previous point to be in a JSON format, or set the content-type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" if you encoded the message object in the previous point.

6- Finally, you need to make sure that your request url is posting to yourapilocatio/api/Messaging url.

Also, you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867153/web-api-2-http-post-method/26955917#26955917).

Hope this helps.